# AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'getTransactionCount'

Tags: python, web3py

I am trying to deploy this code to get the latest transaction and I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/elly/practice/web3/deploy.py", line 72, in
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'getTransactionCount'

Thank you!

Bellow I add the code:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import os
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

install_solc("0.6.0")

# Solidity source code
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi
abi = json.loads(
    compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["metadata"]
)["output"]["abi"]

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://0.0.0.0:8545"))
chain_id = 1337

if chain_id == 4:
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
    print(w3.clientVersion)

my_address="0x6a85d8EB15819bA2C4aeCd242eF8BDAf545ffb75"
private_key="0x1577d778562d1fa5b89ff9581245ea20f7c9edc3fa85771f254a7628bbb0f856"

# Create the contract in Python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
print(nonce)
```

I was trying to get the latest transaction but I got this error AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'getTransactionCount'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think method **getTransactionCount()** is deprecated in favor of **get_transaction_count()**

So, you should try

```
# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_address)
```